# How can I connect to an established server (NOT localhost) with node.js & socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, vercel

I am very new to web servers / node.js / socket.io and I'm trying to make a very simple website just to learn how to connect 2 people. All of the tutorials I've found teach you how to run your app on localhost, but I want to run it on a server so everyone can access it.

I found this hosting website - Zeit-Now - and managed to put my website online. My website works just fine on localhost, but I can't get it to work when i put it online. I think the problem is in these 2 lines in my code, where the '???' are.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>A2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="sendMsg" type="text" placeholder="TYPE TO SEND">
    <input id="receiveMsg" type="text" placeholder="RECEIVE HERE">
    <button id="sendBtn">Send</button>

    <script>

var socket = io.connect('https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh/');

var sendMsg = document.getElementById('sendMsg');
var receiveMsg = document.getElementById('receiveMsg');
var sendBtn = document.getElementById('sendBtn');

// Emit events
sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: sendMsg.value
    });
});

// Listen for events
socket.on('chat', data => {
    receiveMsg.value = data.message;
});

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('Connection! ->', socket.id);

    socket.on('chat', data => {
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });
});
```

I've also tried:

```
var socket = io.connect(https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh/);
```

and

```
var server = app.listen(80, https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh/);
```

I expect my website to read what is written in the first input field and output it in the second one when clicked send (which works fine on localhost), but it doesn't work when I put it online with Zeit-Now.

Edit:

now.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "web-socket-2",
    "builds": [{
            "src": "public/**/*",
            "use": "@now/static"
        },
        {
            "src": "*.js",
            "use": "@now/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [{
        "src": "/",
        "dest": "public/index.html"
    }]
}
```

I have a `#websocket-2` folder with `now.json`, `index.js` and `public` folder. In `public` folder I have `index.html`.

How can I make it work on this website: https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem you face at the moment is that you want to run the server directly on the website. But it's need to be run by node like this: 
`node index.js`. 
Therefore you need access to the server like some ssh access and then start it there with the command named above. Based on the logs, I can say that the client can't find the server. 
You also need to make sure that it resolves to the right path. 
Start it with `app.listen(80)` and then try to connect to
`https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh:80`

Comment: it doesn't work when i try to connect to `https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh:80`. Are you familiar with the Zeit-Now hosting? I'm new to all of this, but from what I understand, it runs `node index.js` and installs `node_modules` and the dependencies on the website, and then runs it. There's also a `now.json` file where I've specified to run the `index.js` file with `node` command, and the `index.html` to be static. Should I change this?

Comment: ok I'm not familiar with this. you should also check if the name-resolving works. maybe it starts is with some subpath?

Comment: Could you please clarify? I am not following.

Comment: have you included '<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>' the socket.io script on your client side? it doesn't seem to find it. pls open your dev tools in the browser and look at the logs

Comment: I am connecting socket.io with cdnjs. I don't think that is the problem. I'll edit the question to show all my index.html code. When you say it doesn't seem to find it, are you checking from the link of the website I posted?

Comment: you at least need to configure a port for the server and then connect to this port

Answer (score 0):

try this

const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketio(server);

server.listen(80, '0.0.0.0');

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server has websockets enabled. (It does not actually need websockets, but it will use it if possible for better transport)

Reading about zeit.co I can see they dont support websockets, not sure if they support sucket either. I would recommend you hitting them up with email to confirm this if code below does not help you.

To run connection on client side, after you have installed socket.io-client or after you have included script in header, which you have.

You simply connect using io.connect('SERVER URL') which will return your socket connection instance. (no need to pass server if running on same server)

```
const socket = io.connect('http://youserver.com'); 
// You can listen to conenct and disconnect to track your connection
socket.on('connect', socket => {
    console.log('Connected', socket.id); 
});
```

Thats it on client side.

On server side, you need to pass server to your socket.io module

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
// You can listen to your socket connecting through connect and disconnect
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  console.log('socket connected', socket);
});
```

You can track your errors on client side using 'error' event, and make sure to check your console to see the logs about the connection.

In case you are using express server, and socket is raising 404 errors in console, make sure you initiate server using http instead of express.

```
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server); 

// your socket and routes

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3500, () => {
   console.log(`Localhost working on ${process.env.PORT || 3500}`);
}
```

Comment: I have this done already with: `const io = socket(server)` on server side. Also `const socket = io.connect('https://web-socket-2.quaei.now.sh/')` on client side doesn't seem to work. Edit: I forgot to mention that tried your suggestion also, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I tried it earlier, because someone else suggested it. It didn't work.

Comment: Pls test it once again using
const app = express(); 
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

Comment: I tested it, it didn't work :(. I've edited the index.js in the question, could you please see if I have done something wrong? If everything is okay, then you say there's no possibility to do what I want with zeit.co? Do you know another free hosting app / website which can allow me to do what I want?

Comment: Move const app = express(); above const server line. You are passing app to server and it is not declared

Comment: Did it. Still no success.

Comment: Check updated answer (last code section) and tell me when you run node in local, do you get any errors

Comment: Ok good, so local works, you can remove server name in io.connect and make sure it works as well, then try pushing it live

Comment: I removed it and it worked locally, but doesn't work on the website.

Comment: Are you sure have published everything correctly to website ?

Comment: you said you have read the documentation, right? I used `@now/node` for the index.js file and `@now/static` for the index.html file. Is this okay? I'll add the now.json file to the question in a minute

Comment: Hmm not sure why you are still getting 404 on your site for socket, as if it is not activated on server side. Either server is not restarted or there is some completely different raising this error. (check your console/network on site, you can clearly see it acts like socket is not activated on server side)

Comment: I've been trying on and off for a year to put a simple website online to be accessible by anyone... I always give up after 2-3 of days of no success. Do you know any other website/app which can host my website successfully for free? If not thank you so much for trying to help me.